# Quadratic Calculator gives Nan

Tags: javascript, math

I'm writing a react app to solve the quadratic formula. When I enter `a=1 b=7 c=10`, or any valid numbers for a quadratic, it returns `NaN[Object]NaN`. Can someone please help, here is my code:

```
  quadraticFormula(a, b, c) {
    var root = -b + Math.sqrt(b, 2) - (4 * a * c);
    var plusAnswer = (-b + Math.sqrt(root))/(2*a);
    var minusAnswer = (-b + Math.sqrt(root))/(2*a);

    document.getElementById('answers').innerHTML = plusAnswer + <br/> + minusAnswer;
  }
```

Comment: With the input you gave `root` is negative. When you call `Math.sqrt()` of that negative number on the next lines it returns NaN. No number multiplied by itself is negative (unless they are _imaginary_).

Comment: That formula doesn't look at all right. Also I'm pretty sure `Math.sqrt` only takes one parameter - what are you expecting `Math.sqrt(b, 2)` to do?

Comment: I typed it out wrong. I got it solved now, thanks all:)

Answer (score 1):

Your formula for `root` in incorrect. It should be `Math.sqrt((b * b) - (4 * a * c))`

Also, you are not using `-` in `minusAnswer`.

```
function quadraticFormula(a, b, c) {
  var root = Math.sqrt((b * b) - (4 * a * c))
  var plusAnswer = (-b + root) / (2 * a)
  var minusAnswer = (-b - root) / (2 * a)

  document.getElementById('answers').innerHTML = plusAnswer + <br/> + minusAnswer;
}
```

HTH